# How to version shared object file created using GCC for Linux

Tags: c++, c, version, shared-libraries

How to version shared object file created using GCC for Linux

Please explain it with few examples

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++ (the GNU C Compiler or the GNU Compiler Collection)?  What have you tried?  What have you researched?  Which other questions did you look at that didn't help you?

Comment: I think the question is too broad. Please narrow it down.

Comment: We are uisng a C++ shared object file which is to be deployed in Linux environment

Comment: Requirement is to distinguish the file with the different versions of the build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can exist multiple version of the shared library in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

For example:

```
/usr/lib/libform.so -> libform.so.5
/usr/lib/libform.so.5 -> libform.so.5.9
/usr/lib/libform.so.5.9
/usr/lib/libform.so.6 -> libform.so.6.0
/usr/lib/libform.so.6.0
```

The symbolic link exists in the above example because, while linking if you just mention `-lform`, it is automatically going to pick the correct library for you based on the symlink.

When a binary is linked against a set of shared libraries, it is going to request for a particular version of the library. The list of libraries, a binary depends upon can be figured out using `ldd`

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/python
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffffa5fe000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007ff6e9b6c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff6e9950000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff6e95ab000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff6e93a7000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ff6e91a4000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff6e8ead000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff6e9f0a000)
```

In the above example, `python` is dependent on `libm.so.6` and not just `libm.so`.

The versioning in the library file name is of this form usually:

```
libSOMETHING.so.VERSION
libSOMETHING.so.MAJOR_VERSION.MINOR_VERSION
```

Some libraries also have sub-minor numbers or patch numbers sometimes.

Each library embeds a string called `soname` within the library which both the compile-time and run-time linker check for version compatibility.

For example binaries compiled against `libform.so.5` will work with `libform.so.5.9` and `libform.so.5.9.1` but not with `libform.so.6` because of the change in the major version number.

To build the `soname` information into the library, you need to do this:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.1  -o libfoo.so.1.0.0 foo.c bar.c baz.c
```

From the man page of `ld`:

```
-soname=name
 When creating an ELF shared object, set the internal DT_SONAME
 field to the specified name.  When an executable is linked with
 a shared object which has a DT_SONAME field, then when the
 executable is run the dynamic linker will attempt to load the
 shared object specified by the DT_SONAME field rather than the
 using the file name given to the linker.
```